# Occurance of Values in a Dictionary C#

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a way that I have a dictionary and I need to get only the  pair that occurs more than once  in Linq
?
for example in

```
{1, "entries"},  
{2, "images"},
{3, "views"},
{4, "images"},
{5, "results"},
{6, "images"},
{7, "entries"}
```

I get

```
{1, "entries"}, 
{2, "images"},
{6, "images"},
{7, "entries"}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This requires iterating through the Dictionary, which defeats the main point of using a Dictionary.

Comment: ok here is the problem i have i need to query the db and do that to the dictionary returned. is there a way to do that directly with MYSQL, i mean get only the rows where a certain field has more than once occurrence

Comment: Something like:

select table.key, table.value
from table
join (select value, count(key) as Count
      from table
      group by value) as ValueCount
   on table.Value = ValueCount.Value
where ValueCount.Count >= 2

Comment: wont be more efficient do that with the dictionary I mean creating such SQL query would take alot of time in a big DB I suppose it is better let DB handle a simpler query then work on the dictionary

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you mean only the *values* that occur more than once, you can do group the key/value pairs by value, filter out the groups with only one item and select the common group key (original value that appears multiple times) from what remains:

```
var multiples = dictionary.GroupBy(p => p.Value)
                          .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                          .Select(g => g.Key);
```

If you want all pairs of keys/values where the values occur more than once, this variation will do it:

```
var multiples = dictionary.GroupBy(p => p.Value)
                          .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                          .SelectMany(g => g);
```

The only difference is in the last step, where after casting out groups with just one value the contents of all remaining groups are "unwrapped" into a single sequence of key/value pairs.

In the latter  case, you can turn the results back into a dictionary (essentially filtering out values that appear only once) by following up with

```
.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value)
```

The last example, in query form:

```
var multiples = from pair in dictionary
                group pair by pair.Value into grp
                where grp.Count() > 1
                from pair in grp select pair;
```

Comment: What would these look like with LINQ query notation?

Comment: @Gabe `from p in dictionary group p by p.Value into g where g.Count() > 1 select g.Key`

Comment: well what if i want to return a dictionary I mean i need to remove the values that has no multiple occurrence from the dictionary a

Comment: @lighty you can create new dictionary from multiples (second sample) with `ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value)` call

Comment: @Jon in query form, wouldn't there be `pair` name conflict?

Comment: @Gabe: I expanded the last one into query form.

Comment: @lighty: Very easy, I incorporated what lazyberezovsky wrote above into the answer.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: To be completely frank, this is the kind of fact that I do not bother remembering. But I did compile the samples before answering and the compiler did not complain.

Comment: @lazy: I believe that the scope of `pair` does not extend beyond the `group by`, so the name is available for use again.

Answer (score 2):

```
var res = dict.GroupBy(x => x.Value).Where(y => y.Count() > 1);
```

if you want to get a Dictionary:

```
var res = dict.GroupBy(x => x.Value)
              .Where(y => y.Count() > 1)
              .SelectMany(z => z)
              .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, k => k.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<int,string> d = new Dictionary<int,string>();
d.Add(1, "entries");
d.Add(2, "images");
d.Add(3, "views");
d.Add(4, "images");
d.Add(5, "results");
d.Add(6, "images");
d.Add(7, "entries");

d.GroupBy(x => x.Value)
 .Where(x=>x.Count()>1)
 .SelectMany(x => x)
 .ToDictionary
 (
     x => x.Key,
     x=>x.Value
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

With these extension methods you have a (little bit) faster and general solution (works on all IEnumarable sources):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> Duplicates<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> selector)
    {
        var grouped = source.GroupBy(selector);
        var moreThen1 = grouped.Where(i => i.IsMultiple());
        return moreThen1.SelectMany(i => i);
    }

    public static bool IsMultiple<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
        return enumerator.MoveNext() && enumerator.MoveNext();
    }
}
```

Fill the source:

```
// Create the source
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>
    {
        {1, "entries"},
        {2, "images"},
        {3, "views"},
        {4, "images"},
        {5, "results"},
        {6, "images"},
        {7, "entries"}
    };
```

Here are 3 options (each option is improved):

```
// More or less the same solution as other answers
var multiples1 = dictionary.GroupBy(p => p.Value)
                            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                            .SelectMany(g => g);

// A little bit faster because IsMultiple does not enumerate all values 
// (Count() iterates to the end, which is not needed in this case).
var multiples2 = dictionary.GroupBy(p => p.Value)
                            .Where(g => g.IsMultiple())
                            .SelectMany(g => g);

// Easy to read
var multiples3 = dictionary.Duplicates(p => p.Value);
```